# DAX AVG of Group Applied but returned for one specific Employee?

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

I have data as follows

```
EmployeeID  Cycle   Val  Group
1            1      6      A
2            1      5      A
```

My desired result is as follows:

```
EmployeeID  Cycle GroupVal
1            1     5.5
2            1     5.5
```

I have written 2 Measures as follows:
Emp_AVG: CALCULATE(AVERAGE(EmployeeFeedback, EmployeeFeedback[Val] > 0)

Group_AVG: CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(EmployeeFeedback[Emp_AVG],EmployeeFeedback[Emp_AVG] >0)

My thought process is that the Group_AVG is averaging the avg of all employees PER GROUP however since i need the results for a SPECIFIC employee, as soon as i introduce that column, it starts slicing by the Employee and the Group avg becomes inaccurate. I guess i need to generate Group Avgs before i do any employee filtering..how?

I am running a DAX query as follows:

```
EVALUATE SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(

EmployeeFeedback[EmployeeID],

EmployeeFeedback[Cycle],

"Group Val", [Group_AVG] 

)
```

I need the EmployeeID to filter it down to an employee but because of EmployeeID, the Group AVG gets screwed. Without EmployeeID, Group AVG is correct but then there is no way to filter it for a specific Employee!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to provide the ALLEXCEPT() argument to the CALCULATE function.

Btw, I believe there's an error in your Emp_AVG measure.

Try this:

Employee Average

```
Emp_AVG = 
CALCULATE(
AVERAGE(EmployeeFeedback[Val]), 
EmployeeFeedback[Val] > 0)
```

Group Average

```
Grp_Avg = 
CALCULATE(EmployeeFeedback[Emp_AVG], 
ALLEXCEPT(EmployeeFeedback,EmployeeFeedback[Group]))
```

Result:

[image: Result Power BI]

Comment: Thanks..that works! and what if i need to exclude certain Employees from Grp_AVG..say there is a Active_IND, how can i make sure the Grp AVG only Averages where Active_IND = 1 ?

Comment: It all depends on your datamodel and relations, but you should be able to add [Active_IND] = 1 as extra argument to the CALCULATE function. Like: 
Grp_Avg = 
CALCULATE(EmployeeFeedback[Emp_AVG], 
[Active_IND] = 1,
ALLEXCEPT(EmployeeFeedback,EmployeeFeedback[Group])). Or add it to the Emp_Avg of course.

Comment: TJ - i made a separate question with dummy data since i think i am doing something wrong, i would appreciate your input
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659936/dax-avg-of-group-at-qtr-level-and-at-fy-level

Comment: Will look at it. This question is closed / answered right?